# Translation of a Macklemore lyric

Tags: motto, english-to-latin-translation, song-lyrics

We are creating our own family crest, and would like a translation of a lyric "no freedom til we're equal". I've looked on Google Translate, but quickly realised it's going to end up reading like a dodgy tattoo. I can see that changing the wording on this slightly, gives very different translations, so I guess I'm looking for the closest in style and meaning. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! That's a nice question, but in order to be on-topic it is expected that you show some previous effort at translating. Do you mind giving it a try?

Answer (score 7):

The following phrase should suit you just fine if your desire is an entirely literal translation, rather than something more pragmatic:

> *Lībertās nūlla dōnec aequālēs sumus.*
>
> or *Lībertātem nūllam habēbimus dōnec aequālēs sumus*.

Which translates literally to:

> *No freedom until we are equal.*
>
> *We shall have no freedom until we are equal.*

I included *habēbimus* in the original phrase as I felt that it made more clear to whom the freedom would belong; however, it can be dropped without removing any critical meaning.

Since you mentioned that this phrase would be included in a family crest and a tattoo, you probably don't want either to have the orthography of my previously provided quote, but rather, in the orthography of Classical Latin (all capitals, lack of a letter *uU*, apices marking long vowels, etc):

> *LIBERTAS•NVLLA•DONEC•AEQVALES•SVMVS*
>
> or *LIBERTATEM•NVLLAM•HABEBIMVS•DONEC•AEQVALES•SVMVS*

But, the final style is obviously up to you. You can read more about the orthography of Classical Latin (with both formal and informal orthographies described) [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_spelling_and_pronunciation).

Comment: Not sure if _donec_ needs a subjunctive, or it is optional. _Donec aequales simus_?

Comment: @Rafael Are you familiar with *donec eris felix multos numerabis amicos*?

Comment: @Rafael A quick glance at some relevant sources (namely this: http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/dum-d%C5%8Dnec-and-quoad) seems to indicate that the present, future, and future perfect indicative can be/are used with *dōnec*.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I wasn't, thank you. But in your cite, both verbs are in future. Maybe _donec aequales erimus_, then? The combo donec+present indicative sounds counter-intuitive to me

Comment: @EthanBierlein, sounds convincing. Thank you!

Comment: @Rafael I couldn't resist writing an answer in hexameter, following Ovid's good example. It just took me a while to figure out how to word it.

Comment: My latin is rusty, but is "libertatem nullam habebimus" more natural than "libertatem non habebimus"? I had the impression that the latter style of negation is more common in Latin.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I can't say that I'm sure if there is a pragmatic difference between either of those two statements - I simply opted for providing the most literal translation as possible in my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your translations. We can now order our flag!

Comment: @rachel I'd be interested in seeing the final result, if possible! :)

Answer (score 7):

Your motto made me recall Ovid's famous line:

> *Donec eris felix multos numerabis amicos.*
>   As long as you are happy you will have many friends.

Imitating this and holding on to hexameter, I arrived at this suggestion:

> *Donec eris mihi par poteris tibi vivere liber.*
>   As long as you are my equal you can live your own life free.

This is not exactly what you wished.
I needed some poetic licence to fit the metric constraints, but I personally feel that hexameter makes a motto more classy.